# Copy files failure

Tags: vmware

I can't copy hidden folders (like `.git` or `.vs`) from `Windows 10` host machine to VMWare `Windows 11` virtual machine that runs in VM Workstation 16. I'm getting error:

```
Cannot scan local directory. You might not have permission to perform the operation.

Canceling the file copy operation.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using VMware V17 and virtual machines here.

Copy the hidden (and special) files on the host to c:\temp on the host. Make sure c:\temp is permitted to Everyone.

Now the Windows 11 machine can browse the host c:\temp and move or copy the files to Windows 11.

This will certainly help if the host files are in a protected (secured) folder, which might be the case here.

Of course make sure VMware Tools are installed. That may have been happened when the Guest machine was installed, but do look in the system tray to ensure the tools were properly installed